# Insert elements into array nested in a hash table

Tags: powershell

I have a hash table like this:

```
$Arguments = @{
    Name = $DataSourceName
    DriverName = "MS Access"
    SetPropertyValue = @(
         "Server=$ServerIpAddress",
         "Description=$Description"
         "CurrentDomain=$DomainName"
    )
    ErrorAction = 'Stop'
}
```

If I want to insert entries into the array `SetPropertyValue`. How can I achieve this? I tried:

```
$Arguments.SetPropertyValue.Add("Database=$DatabaseName")
```

But this does not work.

Comment: The array type does not contain an `Add()` method (see [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$Arguments.SetPropertyValue += "Database=$DatabaseName"
```

This will append an item to the existing array. The `+=` operator is a shorthand equivalent of doing:

```
$Arguments.SetPropertyValue = $Arguments.SetPropertyValue + "Database=$DatabsaseName"
```

Answer (score 1):

`.Add()` is a method associated with lists in PowerShell but not arrays. So one thing you could do it cast your initial `SetPropertyValue` as an array list. \

```
SetPropertyValue = [System.Collections.ArrayList] @(
     "Server=$ServerIpAddress",
     "Description=$Description",
     "CurrentDomain=$DomainName"
)
```

So with that in place your `Add` statement would succeed.